# Alternate definition of fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, axioms

Is it true that we can define a field as a group $G$ that is isomorphic to its automorphism group?

I believe it's an equivalent definition if addition is the group operation of $G$ and multiplication is the application of the automorphism corresponding to the left element to the right element.

Comment: No, that doesn't make sense. The field of order 9 has additive group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3}$, and multiplicative group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{8}$. Neither of these groups is isomorphic to their automorphism group, nor is the multiplicative group isomorphic to the automorphism group of the additive group.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_2$ has trivial automorphism group.

Comment: Is it possible if we let 0 be the 0 homomorphism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is wrong for a whole bunch of reasons.  If $F$ is a field, there is a map from the set of *nonzero* elements of $F$ to the group of automorphisms of the additive group $(F,+)$.  However, this does not mean that $(F,+)$ is isomorphic to its own automorphism group, for quite a lot of different reasons:

1. $0$ is not included (multiplication by $0$ is not an automorphism of $(F,+)$).
2. Even ignoring $0$, the map is not a homomorphism from $(F,+)$ to its automorphism group.  Adding two elements of $F$ does not correspond to composing the automorphisms given by multiplication by them.  Rather, the map is a homomorphism from the group $(F\setminus\{0\},\cdot)$ (with *multiplication* as the group operation) to the group of automorphisms of $(F,+)$.
3. The map in question is typically not surjective.  That is, $(F,+)$ may have lots of other automorphisms besides those that are given by multiplication by elements of $F$.

(And this is not even getting into the issues you would have going "the other way", starting with a group isomorphic to its automorphism group and getting a field.  For instance, such a group need not be abelian.)

Comment: Is it possible to express the field structure using "purely" group theoretic concepts? Or my attempt not really promising at all?

Comment: I think that depends quite a lot on what you consider to be "purely group theoretic concepts".  It's not clear what you want that to mean or what you hope to get out of such a definition.

Comment: Given abelian $(G,+)$ does it suffice to say there is an abelian subgroup of $Aut(G)$ which is in bijection with $G\setminus\{0\}$?

Comment: No, you still need more than that to get associativity and commutativity of multiplication.  For instance, if $f:G\setminus\{0\}\to Aut(G)$ is your map, then for multiplication to be commutative you need to know that $f(g)(h)=f(h)(g)$ for all $g,h\in G$.

Comment: Can I say $\phi_g(h)=\phi_g(\phi_h(1))=\phi_h(\phi_g(1))=\phi_h(g)$?

Comment: How do you know $\phi_h(1)=h$?  You could add that as an additional assumption and then that would work.

Comment: The bijection seems to have some degrees of freedom... so it's not always possible to select an identity element in $G$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.  You can define $1$ as the element of $g$ which maps to the identity in $Aut(G)$.  This only tells you $\phi_1(h)=h$, though, not $\phi_h(1)=h$.

Comment: So far we've only assumed that there exists a bijection and still have the freedom to choose $1\in G$ and other elements. I'm wondering if this is enough (in fact we can take the image of any injection from $G$ into $Aut(G)$ that happens to be an abelian subgroup)

Comment: No; for instance, you need your injection to also satisfy $\phi_h(1)=h$ for all $h$.  (Also, you shouldn't phrase it as "there exists a bijection"; you need to have a specific bijection chosen as part of your data.)

Comment: Yeah that's true if I want to go the other way. I guess a better question would be "what can the addition group of a field look like".

Comment: Following Eric's suggestions, you will end up with a specific kind of bijection from the *set* $G\setminus\{0\}$ to an Abelian subgroup of $Aut(G)$, satisfying further conditions, and to obtain a field, the composition of automorphisms has to be pulled back on $G\setminus\{0\}$ as multiplication.... How much does it sound better or closer to pure group theory, than simply assuming the usual two Abelian group structures on $G$ and $G\setminus\{0\}$ with the distributivity law?

Comment: "What can the additive group of a field look like" is actually very simple.  A group is the additive group of a field iff it is isomorphic to a direct sum of (one or more) copies of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for some prime $p$ or $\mathbb{Q}$.  This follows from some basic field theory.